# How to remove underscores from a string array in typescript-angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, format

i want to replace all the "_" occurrences from an array like this (TASK_1,TASK_2,TASK_3).

I receive this from the back-end and i cannot use the replace all because the project doesn't support es2021. I need to display the array like this (TASK 1,TASK 2, TASK 3).

I tried this method:

```
formatWithoutUnderScore(valueToFormat:any) {
  return valueToFormat.map((value:any) => value.replace(/_/g, ' '));
}
```

and the used it:

```
this.formatWithoutUnderScore(this.totalTasks);
```

But it does nothing :(

Can someone help?

Comment: `map()` will do what you require. Have you actually assigned the response of the `formWithoutUnderScore()` function to anything? I ask as it creates a new array, it doesn't mutate the existing one.

Comment: Rory's comment should take care of you. I just want to add that you should avoid using `any` as a type - in this case, `valueToFormat` should be `string[]` and `value` should be `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.totalTasks = this.formatWithoutUnderScore(this.totalTasks);
```